# Change Block Binding Without Eval?

Tags: ruby, binding, proc

I realize that you can change the binding of a block using `instance_eval`

```
class Foo
  def bar &block
    instance_eval &block
  end
end

Foo.new.bar { self } # returns the instance
```

But some built in methods accept blocks and in that case it doesn't seem possible to change the binding of the block without messing with the internals of the built in method.

```
class Foo
  def enum &block
    Enumerator.new &block
  end
end

Foo.new.enum { self }.each {} # returns main!!!
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I'm pretty certain you cannot do that in either 1.8 or 1.9. Rubinius is bound to have a way, but not the standard Ruby. Not without any C code, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around it this way:

```
class Foo
  def enum &block
    Enumerator.new do |*args|
      instance_exec *args, &block
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm confident that you cannot change the binding of an existing `Proc` short of `instance_eval`/`instance_exec`-ing it.