# How to use define_method in an included module to create methods?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want a class method, `step`, which dynamically creates instance methods.

```
step(:start) do |payload|
  puts payload
end
```

This would create the equivalent of:

```
def start(payload)
  payload
end
```

The trouble I am having is getting a block passed to the class method evaluate in the context of the instance.

The problem seems to be that the block, because it is a closure, is evaluated in the context of where is was defined, the class.

```
module Steps
  def step(name, &block)
    define_method(name) do |payload|
      self # => Foo instance
      block.call(payload)
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  extend Steps

  step(:start) do |payload|
    self # => Foo class
    payload # => 1
    self.data # => undefined method `data' for Foo:Class (NoMethodError)
  end

  def data
    'DATA'
  end
end

puts Foo.new.start(1)
```

Is it possible to have the block evaluated in the context of the instance?

The closest I have come is using `instance_eval` however I can't figure out how to pass the argument `payload` to the block:

```
define_method(name) do |payload|
  instance_eval(&block)
end
```

When I do the above `self` in the passed block is an instance of `Foo` so I can call `data`, but how to access `payload`?

Answer (score 0):

> instance_exec
>
> Executes the given block within the context of the receiver (obj). In
>   order to set the context, the variable self is set to obj while the
>   code is executing, giving the code access to obj’s instance variables.
>   Arguments are passed as block parameters.

```
define_method(name) do |payload|
  instance_exec(payload, &block)
end
```

ref: [Change Block Binding Without Eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587050/change-block-binding-without-eval)